# Possible to set SSH listen IP(s) using wildcard?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Have a series of Ubuntu Servers (16.10) with ten IP addresses configured through aliasing in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I'd like to restrict SSH connection to one IP address per machine. For example; if the machine has the IP addresses 192.168.1.20 - 192.168.1.29 I'd like SSH to only listen on 192.168.1.20.

Is it possible to set `ListenAddress` using wildcards in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? For example: `ListenAddress *.*.*.*0` rather than manually configuring each and every server to listen on a specific IP.

If this (or another method) is possible it would simplify our configuration scripts. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be better off having SSH listen on all IPs and control access via firewall.

Comment: Since you mention scripts; it may be worthwhile writing a short script to append / insert the appropriate `ListenAddress` directives based on a supplied range.

Comment: Can I assume that using wildcards is not possible? In my case, I am interested in a listen address like 192.168.1.*